# view not called after controler call from javascript

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller

I am trying to implement a javascript function which could make an ajax call to my controller. Then the controller can display a view.
The call is done but the view is not displayed.

Here is my intial view :

```
<div class="col-xs-12">

    <button id="button"> Test </button>

</div>
```

Here is the js function :

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {

    $.ajax({

        type:'GET',
        url :"doSomething",

        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success',data);
        },

        error:function(exception){
            console.log('Exeption:'+exception);
        }

    });

});
```

There is the controller :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/doSomething")
public class PingController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView withParam(ModelAndView modelView) {

        modelView.setViewName("myView");
        modelView.addObject("pageviews", 320000);

        return modelView;

    }

}
```

However, if I remove my js and change my initial view as :

```
<div class="col-xs-12">

    <a href="<c:url value="/doSomething" />" > Test </a>

</div>
```

That works, myView is displayed

Comment: What are you expecting to be displayed as a result of the AJAX call?  The only thing you're doing in the success callback is: `console.log('success',data)`  Is this successfully logging to the console?

Comment: This is successfully displayed on the console. I must have misunderstood something. I thought that : the controller call is done, then the controller return the modelView and the view is displayed in the website. This is done with the second implementation I talked about but not the first

Comment: Well, if the expected response of the populated view is being successfully logged to the console, then the code is working.  The controller is returning the view.  But all the AJAX code is doing is just logging it to the console.  It's not refreshing the page because, well, the point of AJAX is to not refresh the page.  If you just want to navigate to the new page then the second implementation would be how you do that.  What's the goal that you're trying to accomplish with AJAX?

Comment: I just wanted to test how I could display a view. If I understand your point, my second implementation is the correct way to display my new view. The ajax request should be restricted to a call for web service for example.

Comment: Well, you can make any valid AJAX call that you like.  The point is that it's up to you what to do with the response.  Currently you do exactly one thing with the response... log it to the console.  If this is successfully happening then the code is working.  But yes, if you want to direct the user to another page then that's what clicking on a link does.  So there's really no need for AJAX there.

Comment: Ok I got it, thank you for your response.